# Navigating an employee tree recursively in Python

Tags: python, recursion

I was recently posed this problem, but am not very adept at writing recursive functions. How would you solve it?

You have a company structure as follows:

```
#          employee: manager
company = {
           '17': '15', 
           '16': '15',
           '10': '5', 
           '15': '10',  
           '5': '4', 
           '4': 'NULL'
           }
```

Each number is the person's id. Person 4 is the CEO and has a NULL value since there is no manager. 
How could you write a recursive function `reportsTo(eid, mid)` that returns:

- `reportsTo('17', '4')` --> `True`
- `reportsTo('15', '16')` --> `False`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
  def reportsTo(eid, mid):
       m2 = company[eid]
       if m2 == "NULL": return False
       return m2 == mid or reportsTo(m2, mid)
```

Comment: +1 This is short and beautiful! Minor pep8 nit: missing space before ``return`` and after commas in reportsTo (twice).

Comment: +1 and on the subject of minor PEP8 nits, the spaces after the open parentheses are superfluous.

Answer (score 3):

The first step in making a recursive function is determining base cases. This has two.

1. employee directly reports to manager: return true.
2. employee's manager is null: return false, because we've reached the CEO.

If we've gotten this far, we return a call to the same function, using company[e] instead of the original employee. It goes up the chain until it reaches one of the base cases.

This will only work if employees have only one direct manager. It gets more complicated if there are more.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what you want to do, you could do something like this (pseudocode):

```
function reportsTo(eid, mid):
    if company[eid] is mid          # base case number 1
        return True
    else if company[eid] is null    # base case number 2
        return False
    else
        return reportsTo(company[eid], mid)
```

If you want to get your head around recursive functions, I'd try implementing really trivial things, but recursively. For example, make a recursive pair of functions, one checking if a number is even and one checking if it is odd.

Edit:

Python:

```
def reportsTo(eid, mid):
    if company[eid] == mid:          # base case number 1
        return True
    elif company[eid] is None:    # base case number 2
        return False
    else
        return reportsTo(company[eid], mid)
```

(I changed the manager for the CEO to `None` rather than a string saying `'NULL'` because it seemed better to me).

Alternatively:

```
def reportsTo(eid, mid):
    if eid in company:
        return False
    return (eid == mid) or (reportsTo(company[eid], mid))
```

Comment: I dont think this will ever end up returning False given his dict (there is no `null` in python, and he is using `'NULL'` (the string) +1 though since you are right other than that :P

Comment: @JoranBeasley I was just giving pseudocode because I thought `null` would be a typical language-agnostic kind of thing.

Comment: hehe ... well the rest is actual python :P so I didnt realize it was pseudocode :P (and you are right that using None is better form than the string "NULL")

Comment: @JoranBeasley I know, Python's so close to pseudocode! I tried to emphasise that it wasn't actual code by using `is`, but then I realised that that's possible in Python

Answer (score 1):

Here's a quick solution, using recursion:

```
def reportsTo(e, m):
    if e == 'NULL':
        return False
    assert e in company
    if m == company[e]:
        return True
    else:
        return reportsTo(company[e], m)
```

**EDIT** Although the above code is technically correct, it's a good exercise to try to improve it.

As per comments from others:

- The assert is not needed. `company[e]` will raise a `KeyError` if the key is not present, so this code can be removed.
- `company[e]` is potentially calculated more than once. For speed, and readability, allocate it to a local variable.
- The check for `e` being `'NULL'` can be moved to checking for `company[e]` being `'NULL'`; this may save one function call.
- The `if`-`else` can be turned into an `or`, exploiting the fact that `or` is lazy, and strict in its left argument i.e. it will not evaluate its right argument and therefore the function will not recurse, whenever its left argument is `True`).

Comment: the dictionary access is basically an assert (it will raise a KeyError, instead of an AssertionError), as such the assert is likely superfluous (lol is that the right word?) (+1 all the same, just a minor nitpick)

Comment: Correct. Actually I like your solution better, I'll vote for it. :-)

Comment: Note that you can disable assert in Python with the option -O (optimize). This basically means that your code is error-prone. Just check "if e in company: ...". This way you can also remove the first check: if e == NULL. :)

Comment: Thanks for all the tips - I've edited my answer to discuss how the code can be improved.